# Why does multiplcation by 1/2 not give the same value as multiplication by .5?

Tags: java, math, operators

Like the title says, I'm a bit confused to why multiplying by 1/2 is somehow different then multiplying by 0.5.

**Take the following code:**

```
double range = (46/2) + (1/2 * height); //say height is 10
```

**this returns:**

```
23
```

Which is clearly an incorrect value, it seems to be only evaluating the 46/2 part.

**However, when I do this:**

```
double range = (46/2) + (.5 * height); //say height is 10
```

**this returns:**

```
28
```

Which is correct.

So why is this the case?

(I'm sure this has been asked before at some point, however I'm not sure what to call this situation and a search in SO & google did not find me the answer)

Comment: try to wrap 1/2 in parenthesis like (1/2), it should work

Comment: @VivekSolanki no that didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: oh yeah right, sorry my bad, i missed type conversion :)

Comment: @VivekSolanki okay no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1/2 * height` is `0` because `1/2` is `0` due to integer semantics.
Try `1.0/2 * height` and you will get the same result

Comment: Aha! Okay, probably should have known that. Oh well, now I do. Thanks. I'll accept your's since I belive you answered first. Thanks to @Arachnid Hivemind and Kondu for quick response.

Comment: It is something you (and me and I guess everyone) tend to do wrong over and over again ^^

Answer (score 2):

Ok so what is happening is that in the first example the (1/2 * 10) is being converted into an integer so it is then at 0 an then it was 23 when added to (46/2). Then when you do (.5 * 10) it is converted to a double then added back to the (46/2) which turns out to be 23 +5

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can only accept one so I'm going to give it to Martin since he got it first.

Comment: Lol its a brutal world.

Comment: Hey it keeps you sharp

Answer (score 1):

Your 1/2 evaluates to 0 as you are not asking for float or double value after evaluating...use the float representation to see the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can only accept one so I'm going to give it to Martin since he got it first